# Generate deterministic hash number between 0 and 1 from string

Tags: javascript, hash, hashcode

I'm looking for a way to 'hash' strings in JavaScript, so that

- the result is deterministic (aways yields same result with the same input string)
- the result is a decimal number between 0 and 1
- the results are (kind of) uniformly spread out in the 0 to 1 space.

For example:

```
decimalHash('hallo world') = 0.145     // some made up number
decimalHash('how are you?') = 0.345    // some made up number
decimalHash('fine, thanks!') = 0.945   // some made up number
```

I've searched for such a method, but all the hash functions I found so far have different characteristics. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Most hash function return a result in some integer range, but otherwise fulfill your other requirements (deterministic and somewhat even spread). Why don't you just map the output of one such hash function to the range 0->1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could built an own by using a value for each chatacter with a factor and sum this value. At the end take only fractional part.

This approach may produce collisions.

```js
const decimalHash = string => {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++)
        sum += (i + 1) * string.codePointAt(i) / (1 << 8)
    return sum % 1;
}

console.log(decimalHash('a'));
console.log(decimalHash('aa'));
console.log(decimalHash('hallo world'));
console.log(decimalHash('how are you?'));
console.log(decimalHash('fine, thanks!'));
```

Comment: This is not going to give you a uniform distribution.